# How to extend an array in Swift?

Tags: arrays, swift, protocols

I have this protocol

```
protocol JsonConvertable {
    init?(_ underlyingValue: UnderlyingValue)
}
```

`UnderlyingValue` is an `enum`:

```
enum UnderlyingValue {
    case string(String)
    case int(Int)
    case double(Double)
    case bool(Bool)
    case array(Array<Dictionary<String, AnyObject>>)
    case dictionary(Dictionary<String, AnyObject>)

    init?(value: JsonConvertable) {
        switch rawValue {
        case let value as [String: AnyObject]: self = .dictionary(value)
        case let value as Array<[String: AnyObject]>: self = .array(value)
        case let value as Double: self = .double(value)
        case let value as Int: self = .int(value)
        case let value as Bool: self = .bool(value)
        case let value as String: self = .string(value)
        default: return nil
        }
    }
}
```

I can extend most types as follows

```
extension String: JsonConvertable {
    init?(_ underlyingValue: UnderlyingValue) {
        switch underlyingValue {
        case .bool(let value): self = value
        default: return nil
    }
}
```

However the Array extension is giving me the error 
`Cannot assign value of type 'Array<Dictionary<String, AnyObject>>' to type 'Array<_>'`

```
extension Array: JsonConvertable {
    init?(_ underlyingValue: UnderlyingValue) {
        switch underlyingValue {
        case .array(let value): self = value
        default: return nil
        }
    }
}
```

I have tried everything I can think of but nothing is working.  I tried to have JsonConvertable conform to ArrayLiteralConvertable, I have tried using generics in the init but I am just starting to understand generics and don't really know how it would be beneficial in this case, the same with AssociatedType.  I have tried to constrict Element. I have been trying to get this to work for 2 whole days and everything I do seems to not make any headway. What am I missing?

Answer (score 4):

In your extension method, you are extending Array which is a type of Array<_> and your _underlyingValue is type of Array<[String:AnyObject]>.

Have you try this way:

```
extension Array where Element:Dictionary<String, AnyObject>, Element:JsonConvertable  {
  init?(_underlyingValue : UnderlyingValue){
      switch _underlyingValue {
        case  .array(let value):
          self = value
        default:
          return nil
      }
  }
}
```

Comment: I will give this a chance once I can get back to my project.  I have tried something similar, I remember getting an error message that you can only constrict Element with a protocol and not a concrete type.

Comment: The error below shows up at the extension signature

`type 'Element' constrained to non-protocol type 'Dictionary<String, AnyObject>`